# Error Translator with latest update

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I have update zf2 on the latest version and i receive this error:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Ft6d/

Some mandatory parameter was added for translation?

This is my translator config:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'it_IT',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
```

and this is what i call inside the Module.php::onBootstrap()

```
$translator = $serviceManager->get('translator’);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that most probably, the [`DiAbstractServiceFactory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/4fe2829353077239aafc9ffe39a15c07bba5b660/library/Zend/ServiceManager/Di/DiAbstractServiceFactory.php) is kicking in before an abstract factory that is responsible of fetching the `MvcTransator` instance.

You will likely have to switch the order in which abstract factories are being used, or remove your `'di'` config from your modules or autoload config, since its presence [will automatically cause addition of the `DiAbstractServiceFactory` to the `ServiceManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/4fe2829353077239aafc9ffe39a15c07bba5b660/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php#L37-L39).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue myself this morning after upgrading from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0.

There's a bug in ZF2.3.0 which causes the Di module to fail when trying to create an instance of the MvcTranslator (see: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5959, where @Ocramius and noopable came up with the solution).

Until the fix is rolled out to the framework, you'll need to change the following code in `Zend\ServiceManager\Di\DiAbstractServiceFactory` from:

```
public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
{
    return $this->instanceManager->hasSharedInstance($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasAlias($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasConfig($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasTypePreferences($requestedName)
        || $this->definitions->hasClass($requestedName);
}
```

to:

```
public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
{
    if ($this->instanceManager->hasSharedInstance($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasAlias($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasConfig($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasTypePreferences($requestedName)
    ) {
        return true;
    }

    if (! $this->definitions->hasClass($requestedName) || interface_exists($requestedName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```